# Moodle - Display category descriptions in front page

Tags: php, moodle

I need to display the **category descriptions in the Front page** in Moodle. I can see that there is no setting for this, as descriptions can be visible only when user enters the category. I have already set the "List of categories" option in the Front page settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting as far as I know. You need to modify (not recommended) or override from your theme (recommended, https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer) the `coursecat_category_content` renderer method (around line 1430 in Moodle 3.7.2 `course/renderer.php`, class `core_course_renderer`) adding something roughly similar to this (according to your needs in terms of formatting, validation and so on):

```
$content .= html_writer::div($chelper->get_category_formatted_description($coursecat));
```